# svn error when checkoutng: "Not authorized to open root of edit operation"

Tags: svn

I have svnserve with current settings:

**svnserve.conf:**

```
anon-access = read #I also tried anon-access = none or comment this line
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz
```

**authz:**

```
[/]
foo = rw

[/Subdir]
foo = rw
bar = rw
```

If user 'bar' try checkout /Subdir folder then he get error: "Not authorized to open root of edit operation".
User foo can do it correctly.

What I can do with this trouble?

Answer (score 4):

I found out that removing the `Satisfy Any` from my apache configuration fixed everything.

Comment: For an Apache hosted SVN Repository this is the correct approach, therefore you get an thumps up from me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**I resolve this issue**
best you will check the svn network by following steps. 
1. Open the SVN Setting, select saved data, click Clear... button of the Authentication data, try one more time, if same issue you got, please follow below steps.
2. Open the SVN Setting, select Network menu, click Edit button of the Subversion server file, Add below line at end of file 
        http-auth-types=basic;digest
3. save that file and try now

Answer (score 0):

I think your authz is wrong.  [/] is a special case for all repositories.  If you want to start authorizing repository paths, you need to put the repository name in there using [reponame:repopath].  For more information:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

Comment: I changed authz to 
[repname:/]
foo = rw

[repname:/Subdir]
foo = rw
bar = rw

but trouble is still exists.
PS. User 'bar' can checkout from /Subdir/subsubdir/

Comment: You might want to make sure that your casing is correct.  Foo and foo are not the same in your authz file.  This applies to usernames, repository names and repository paths.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer at this article: http://wp.evx.me/evolonix/2011/11/27/svn_error_e220000/

There’s an escape-hatch of sorts, one which allows you to trade security features for speed. If you’re not enforcing any sort of per-directory authorization (i.e. not using mod_authz_svn or similar module), then you can disable path-checking. In your httpd.conf or virtual host file, use the SVNPathAuthz directive:

Disabling path checks altogether

```
<Location /repos>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /usr/local/svn
    SVNPathAuthz off
</Location>
```

The SVNPathAuthz directive is “on” by default. When set “off”, all path-based authorization checking is disabled; mod_dav_svn stops invoking authorization checks on every path it discovers.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but solved it in a different way. I had a checkout with a subfolder:

```
SVN\SubDir
```

Like in the example by the topic starter, the account `bar` only had access to SubDir. However, when I tried to update the folder SubDir with the `bar` account, I got the error `Not authorized to open root of edit operation`.

I found out that the reason for this is that it's part of a full checkout. Normally a user with limited rights would only checkout the specific folder, instead of updating within a full checkout. When I made a separate checkout of just the desired folder, `bar` could access it just fine. :)